# How to read a newline from config file using Python ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

I have a config File "Email_Properties.cfg" as below

```
[email_Properties]
Subject=Security keywords Scan Info
Body=securityDetails\n Note : This is an auto generated mail
```

I am using ConfigParser to read file and print the content, Not able to get newLine using \n

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open(r'Email_Properties.cfg'))
body=config.get('email_Properties', 'Body')
print body
```

output:

```
securityDetails\n Note : This is an auto generated mail
```

How i can get NewLine present in the string of Config file ? Expected output as below,

```
securityDetails
Note : This is an auto generated mail
```

Answer (score 4):

ConfigParser escapes `\n` in ini values as `\\n`, so try with something like

```
body.replace('\\n', '\n')
```

FWIW: The question's example is in Python 2, but for users of Python >=3.2: `ConfigParser.read_file()` [replaces](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file) the `ConfigParser.readfp()` which as of then is deprecated. This is *not* affecting the question/solution though.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept answer if this solved your problem :)